# Playing startup and shutdown sounds in Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: sound, startup

What steps should take place in order to do that?

Comment: Go to the path _/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/_ and check the sound files like _desktop-login.ogg_  _desktop-login.ogg.sav_  if not there copy or download sound file which you like and convert into the same format.